# Dynamic generated accordion from php array

Tags: php, html, jquery-ui

Heelo.

I have problem, i am noob in php and i want to dynamic generate accordion from this php array.

```
$main = array ('mainregion1' => array (
        'main_person' => array ( 
            0 => array ( 
                'name' => 'name1', 
                'phone' => '000000000', 
                'email' => 'name@name.com', 
                'important' => true, 
                ),
            ), 
        'subregion1' => array ( 
            0 => array ( 
                'name' => 'name2', 
                'phone' => '000111000', 
                'email' => 'name2@name2.com', 
                'important' => false, 
                ),
            1 => array ( 
                'name' => 'name3', 
                'phone' => '000222000', 
                'email' => 'name3@name3.com', 
                'important' => false, 
                ), 
            ), 
        'subregion2' => array ( 
            0 => array (
                'name' => 'name4', 
                'phone' => '111000111', 
                'email' => 'name4@name4.com',
                'important' => false, 
                ), 
            ),
        ),  
     );
    array ('mainregion2' => array (
        'main_person' => array ( 
            0 => array ( 
                'name' => 'name1', 
                'phone' => '000000000', 
                'email' => 'name@name.com', 
                'important' => true, 
                ),
            ), 
        'subregion1' => array ( 
            0 => array ( 
                'name' => 'name2', 
                'phone' => '000111000', 
                'email' => 'name2@name2.com', 
                'important' => false, 
                ),
            1 => array ( 
                'name' => 'name3', 
                'phone' => '000222000', 
                'email' => 'name3@name3.com', 
                'important' => false, 
                ), 
            ), 
        'subregion2' => array ( 
            0 => array (
                'name' => 'name4', 
                'phone' => '111000111', 
                'email' => 'name4@name4.com',
                'important' => false, 
                ), 
            ),
        ),  
     );
```

I have done this in html http://jsfiddle.net/msx20/9nk9H/4/ . I want to display data from "main" array tagged eith "important" as a parent div and display it content, and the data from subregions arrays display below in accordions in children divs.

But i am noob in php and o dont know exacly how to do it, i have tried the foreach function but i dont understand good the mulidimensionals arrays and play with them.

Could someone help me with this ?

Comment: Get a `var_export()` instead a `var_dump()`, adjust its indentation and put it here instead of this one. It has several dimensions, and it not very legible when one ends/starts.

Comment: Oh, the sub regions have more than one value... See, that's why is better to read like this.

Comment: Look at my code, I've just edited and tested. It is working. But, take care with your `array`, it apparently has some strange `);`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would be something like this. It the indices may not be correct as I cannot see the dimensions clearly in you array.

---

**EDIT:** Take care with your array.

Change this:

```
'subregion2' => array ( 
        0 => array (
            'name' => 'name4', 
            'phone' => '111000111', 
            'email' => 'name4@name4.com',
            'important' => false, 
            ), 
        ),
    ),  
 );
array ('mainregion2' => array (
    'main_person' => array (
    // code ...
```

With:

```
'subregion2' => array ( 
        0 => array (
            'name' => 'name4', 
            'phone' => '111000111', 
            'email' => 'name4@name4.com',
            'important' => false, 
            ), 
        ),
    ),
'mainregion2' => array (
    'main_person' => array ( 
     // code ...
```

If not, you are declaring an array without a `key` or variable.

---

Try this, tested on my localhost, and it is working.

```
  <?
    foreach($main as $k => $v){
    echo "<div>$k</div>";       
    $array = $v;
    foreach($v as $key => $value){          
        if($key == 'main_person'){
          echo "<div class='main'>";
          echo "<p>Name - ".$value[0]['name']."</p>";
          echo "<p>Phone - ".$value[0]['phone']."</p>";
          echo "<p>Email - ".$value[0]['email']."</p>";
          echo "</div>";
          echo "<div id=\"accordion\">";              
        }
          echo "<h3>$key</h3>";
          if(sizeof($value)>1){             
              $subReg = $value;
              foreach ($subReg as $sK => $sV) {
              echo "<div>";
              echo "<p>Name - ".$sV['name']."</p>";
              echo "<p>Phone - ".$sV['phone']."</p>";
              echo "<p>Email - ".$sV['email']."</p>";
              echo "</div>";                  
              }              
          }else{
              echo "<div>";
              echo "<p>Name - ".$value[0]['name']."</p>";
              echo "<p>Phone - ".$value[0]['phone']."</p>";
              echo "<p>Email - ".$value[0]['email']."</p>";
              echo "</div>";

        }           
    }
    echo "</div>";
}   
  ?>
```